# Making font colour negative to the background. iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uilabel

I want to make text in a `UILabel` appear of a color negative to that background it is placed on.

I am placing the label on a web view, and I want that label to be always of a negative colour to the background so that no matter what colour (when web view is scrolled) is exactly below the text, it is always visible in a negative colour.

Thank you.

Comment: please try adding what you have tried and what went wrong. What did you think to do to resolve your problem. This is not a place to ask for code.

Comment: Generally, if you want text to always be visible (think subtitles), you simply use a light color foreground (usually white or yellow) with a dark outline (black).

Comment: Read apple's `Quartz` guides. You can achieve pretty similar effect with `kCGBlendModeDifference`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to do that because the scrolling part of the webView won't be smooth with all those calculations in it. So I suggest you to set a background ImageView to your label and set a image with a negative color to your font color to that ImageView

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be setting the `shadowColor` to the opposite of the `textColor` (for example, white and black, respectively), ensuring that you'll always be able to pick out the text regardless of the web view's background color.

Don't forget to set the `shadowOffset` too!